# Is there any difference between "restart" and "stop/start" for MariaDB (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I had a table crashed in MariaDB and it stopped responding while MariaDB was trying to repair crashed table automatically, and the repairing process seemed to be consuming server resource. I tried to restart MariaDB with "restart" command, but it took longer than usual and after restarting, the repairing process seemed to be still active and MariaDB still was not responding. Then I restarted MariaDB again with "stop" and "start" command, MariaDB stopped and started without taking so long time. After the second restarting, repairing process seemed to be stopped and the main service restored (the main service works without crashed table). I wonder "restart" command does not kill repairing process but "stop" command does. Is that right? Does anyone have idea about the difference of those commands? I use MariaDB 5.5.56 on CentOS 7.

Comment: Both approaches may find different things to do, hence take more or less time.  If you are using MyISAM, switch to InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

If you `systemctl show mysql.service` it should list the `Exec{Start/Stop/Reload}` settings for this service.

`journalctl -u mysql.service` will list the actions taken.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked the setting by "systemctl show mariadb.service", but there were only ExecStart and there wasn't ExecStop or ExecReload. I checked log by "journalctl -u mariadb.service", after "restart" and "stop/start", the messages for those commands were a bit different. For "restart", (Stopping MariaDB..., Starting MariaDB... and Started MariaDB) instead of (Stopping MariaDB..., Stopped MariaDB..., Starting MariaDB... and Started MariaDB) for "stop/start". I am not sure the difference between those messages means the difference of the actions or not. Thanks anyway.